# NotFoundError when restoring tensorflow session

Tags: python, tensorflow

Here is the code:

```
import tensorflow as tf

def save(checkpoint_file='hello.chk'):
    with tf.Session() as session:
        x = tf.Variable(initial_value=[1, 2, 3], name="x")
        y = tf.Variable(initial_value=[[1.0, 2.0], [3.0, 4.0]], name="y")
        not_saved = tf.Variable(initial_value=[[11.0, 2.0], [3.0, 4.0]], name="not_saved")
        session.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
        print(session.run(tf.global_variables()))
        saver = tf.train.Saver([x, y])
        saver.save(session, checkpoint_file)
        print(session.run(tf.global_variables()))
        print("saved!!!!!!!!!!")

def restore(checkpoint_file='hello.chk'):
    with tf.Session() as session:
        saver = tf.train.Saver()
        saver.restore(sess=session, save_path=checkpoint_file)
        print(session.run(tf.global_variables()))

def reset():
    tf.reset_default_graph()

save()
restore("/home/kaiyin/PycharmProjects/text-classify/hello.chk")
```

I am just trying to save and restore some simple variables here, nothing complicated. The saving part seems fine, but I got the following errors when restoring:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/kaiyin/virtualenvs/tensorflow/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 1022, in _do_call
    return fn(*args)
  File "/home/kaiyin/virtualenvs/tensorflow/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 1004, in _run_fn
    status, run_metadata)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/contextlib.py", line 66, in __exit__
    next(self.gen)
  File "/home/kaiyin/virtualenvs/tensorflow/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/errors_impl.py", line 466, in raise_exception_on_not_ok_status
    pywrap_tensorflow.TF_GetCode(status))
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.NotFoundError: Key not_saved not found in checkpoint
     [[Node: save_1/RestoreV2 = RestoreV2[dtypes=[DT_FLOAT], _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0"](_recv_save_1/Const_0, save_1/RestoreV2/tensor_names, save_1/RestoreV2/shape_and_slices)]]

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/kaiyin/PycharmProjects/text-classify/restore.py", line 25, in <module>
    restore("/home/kaiyin/PycharmProjects/text-classify/hello.chk")
  File "/home/kaiyin/PycharmProjects/text-classify/restore.py", line 18, in restore
    saver.restore(sess=session, save_path=checkpoint_file)
  File "/home/kaiyin/virtualenvs/tensorflow/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/training/saver.py", line 1428, in restore
    {self.saver_def.filename_tensor_name: save_path})
  File "/home/kaiyin/virtualenvs/tensorflow/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 767, in run
    run_metadata_ptr)
  File "/home/kaiyin/virtualenvs/tensorflow/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 965, in _run
    feed_dict_string, options, run_metadata)
  File "/home/kaiyin/virtualenvs/tensorflow/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 1015, in _do_run
    target_list, options, run_metadata)
  File "/home/kaiyin/virtualenvs/tensorflow/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 1035, in _do_call
    raise type(e)(node_def, op, message)
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.NotFoundError: Key not_saved not found in checkpoint
     [[Node: save_1/RestoreV2 = RestoreV2[dtypes=[DT_FLOAT], _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0"](_recv_save_1/Const_0, save_1/RestoreV2/tensor_names, save_1/RestoreV2/shape_and_slices)]]

Caused by op 'save_1/RestoreV2', defined at:
  File "/home/kaiyin/PycharmProjects/text-classify/restore.py", line 25, in <module>
    restore("/home/kaiyin/PycharmProjects/text-classify/hello.chk")
  File "/home/kaiyin/PycharmProjects/text-classify/restore.py", line 17, in restore
    saver = tf.train.Saver()
  File "/home/kaiyin/virtualenvs/tensorflow/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/training/saver.py", line 1040, in __init__
    self.build()
  File "/home/kaiyin/virtualenvs/tensorflow/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/training/saver.py", line 1070, in build
    restore_sequentially=self._restore_sequentially)
  File "/home/kaiyin/virtualenvs/tensorflow/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/training/saver.py", line 675, in build
    restore_sequentially, reshape)
  File "/home/kaiyin/virtualenvs/tensorflow/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/training/saver.py", line 402, in _AddRestoreOps
    tensors = self.restore_op(filename_tensor, saveable, preferred_shard)
  File "/home/kaiyin/virtualenvs/tensorflow/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/training/saver.py", line 242, in restore_op
    [spec.tensor.dtype])[0])
  File "/home/kaiyin/virtualenvs/tensorflow/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/gen_io_ops.py", line 668, in restore_v2
    dtypes=dtypes, name=name)
  File "/home/kaiyin/virtualenvs/tensorflow/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/op_def_library.py", line 763, in apply_op
    op_def=op_def)
  File "/home/kaiyin/virtualenvs/tensorflow/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 2327, in create_op
    original_op=self._default_original_op, op_def=op_def)
  File "/home/kaiyin/virtualenvs/tensorflow/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 1226, in __init__
    self._traceback = _extract_stack()

NotFoundError (see above for traceback): Key not_saved not found in checkpoint
     [[Node: save_1/RestoreV2 = RestoreV2[dtypes=[DT_FLOAT], _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0"](_recv_save_1/Const_0, save_1/RestoreV2/tensor_names, save_1/RestoreV2/shape_and_slices)]]


Process finished with exit code 1
```

Tensorflow version:

```
>>> print(tf.__version__)
1.0.1
```

Answer (score 0):

Deleting the list of vars in `tf.train.Saver()` somehow solves the problem. Here is the working code:

```
import tensorflow as tf

filepath = "/home/kaiyin/PycharmProjects/text-classify/hello.chk"

def save(checkpoint_file=filepath):
    with tf.Session() as session:
        x = tf.Variable(initial_value=[1, 2, 3], name="x")
        y = tf.Variable(initial_value=[[1.0, 2.0], [3.0, 4.0]], name="y")
        not_saved = tf.Variable(initial_value=[[11.0, 2.0], [3.0, 4.0]], name="not_saved")
        session.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
        print(session.run(tf.global_variables()))
        saver = tf.train.Saver()
        saver.save(session, checkpoint_file)
        print(session.run(tf.global_variables()))
        print("saved!!!!!!!!!!")

def restore(checkpoint_file='hello.chk'):
    with tf.Session() as session:
        saver = tf.train.Saver()
        saver.restore(sess=session, save_path=checkpoint_file)
        print(session.run(tf.global_variables()[0]))
        print(session.run(x))

def reset():
    tf.reset_default_graph()

save()
restore(filepath)
```